# Distributing a value among multiple fields in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Need help. Working on a school project which accepts an amount of school fees paid and distributes it among the various fields "Tuition", "sports","miscellaneous".

Lets say value for tuition is 200, sports - 250 and miscellaneous is 100. If a person pays 500, it should be able to distribute to the various fields and insert last value in miscellaneous.

I tried to use the if else but facing problem.

Here is my code:

```
if($feespaid>$tuition) {
    $feespaid = $feespaid-$tuition;
} else {
    $tuition=$feespaid;
}
if($feespaid>$sports) {
    $feespaid = $feespaid-$sports;
} else {
    $sports=$feespaid;
}
```

Problem with code is,

- if someone pays 300, a value of 100 is inserted into sports and miscellaneous

Comment: instead of this make an Gui where three different fees are putted separately and comes for saving. Not the combo. Distinguishing them from the combo money is tough (because you cannot declare in what order they paid )

Comment: i have a GUI for admin who specifies the values of the various fields. but say when a student pays a fees and value is entered into the system, it should be able to distribute across the various fields for that particular student

Comment: what happen if a student want to pay 100 rupee for tuition and 100 rupee for miscellaneous and 200 for sport

Comment: tuition, sports and miscellaneous are the breakdown of the school fees. fees breakdown follows priority which is determined by school. student just pays fees as a whole then school breaks it down into various fields cos they have to report to various departments using those breakdowns

Comment: if the order always *tuition*, *sports*, and *misc* - just put the latter in the `if` part, cause `else` always means that the `fees` already used up.

Answer (score 1):

Reading all the comments, it seems that the user pays one time and it will be distributed in this order:

1. If the payment is more than "tuition", then "tuition" will be deducted from the payment and we will move to next part, else, all the amount of the payment will be dedicated to "tuition".
2. If the remainder of the payment more than "sports", then "sports" will be deducted from the payment and we will move to next part, else, all the amount of the payment will be dedicated to "sports".
3. We will dedicate any possible remainder of the payment to the "miscellaneous".

So the code will be like this:

```
<?php
$tuition = 200;
$sports = 250;
$miscellaneous = 100;
$feespaid = 500;

if($feespaid > $tuition){
    $feespaid = $feespaid - $tuition;
}
else{
    $tuition = $feespaid;
    $feespaid = 0;
}

if($feespaid > $sports){
    $feespaid = $feespaid - $sports;
}
else{
    $sports = $feespaid;
    $feespaid = 0;
}

$miscellaneous = $feespaid;
```

Comment: :) you are welcome @EbenezerAbbam, if this answer has solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345806) it and also give it an up-vote.

Comment: @EhsanT: Ahh, you see? It's so unfair :/

Comment: @sepehr, yeah buddy. At least I got a "thank you" comment for this one. I've posted answers that the OP had never seen them. I don't understand if they don't need help, why they bother themselves to post a question in the first place!

Comment: @EhsanT: There was once an OP that copied my answer pasted it into his own answer and then accepted that! Then added a comment: *"It works!"*.

Comment: I feel you bro. Accepting ann up-voting an answer which helped the OP, will increase the chance that this answer will help other users which may face same problem in future and by seeing the accepted mark or a high up-vote, they will trust the solution provided, and then reputation comes in the second place.